# Bottom toolbar shows in iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

My app is embeded in a naviguation controller, I dragged a Empty viewController then added a tool bar at the bottom.

It shows in my storyboard, but when I run on a device/simulator it does not show in the iPad.

I did the same thing on iPhone and it shows.

How do I solve this?

Here's the code that loads:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES ;

}
```

[image: this is the iPad on my storyboard]

I know it's strange to have `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES ;` but my understanding is that the navigation controller has its own bottom bar. And the same code works fine on iPhone.
So im not sure why I still get an issue.

When I set it to `is Initial view controller` then it shows.

Comment: I am in the same boat. I have a toolbar that I manage in my view controller (added via Storyboard, available as property) and it works as expected on iPhone using `setItems:animated`. On the iPad there is no toolbar. Any progress?

Comment: @ToddB Hi I posted my solution please upvote it if it solves your issue

Comment: It didn't help. :(. My issue might be slightly different. I have an iPhone app, and when the app is opened on an iPad the toolbar is gone. It works fine (same exact app) on the iPhone. Stange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue adding the transculent bar to the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone encountering this issue.